# Lua oop middleclass spawn enemies with random x coordinate

Tags: oop, object, random, lua, love2d

I make a game with lua/LÖVE and i use the middleclass library for OOP, but i have a problem, my game is a space shooter game with a base class "entity" a subclass "player" and "meteor" (enemy that fall from the top of the screen with a random x coordinate) but i don't know how to make the random spawn system for the meteor (a random x coordinate).

```
Entity = class('Entity')

function Entity:initialize(x, y, width, height, image)
  self.x = x
  self.y = y
  self.width = width
  self.height = height
  self.image = image
end

function Entity:draw()
  love.graphics.draw(self.image, self.x, self.y)

    end
```

meteor.lua = https://pastebin.com/9WLENrLN gameState.lua = https://pastebin.com/p0fH1XmN

(the game file)

Everytimes that i launch the game, the x coordinate of the meteor object is the same, i want to spawn one meteor with a random x coordinate every 2 seconds, but i don't know how to do that. I think that i've made something wrong but i don't know. :/

```
function Meteor:initialize()
  self.speed = 400
  meteorWidth = 45
  meteorHeight = 40
  self.x = love.math.random(0, WINDOW_WIDHT - meteorWidth)
  meteorY = 0 - meteorWidth
  Entity.initialize(self, self.x, meteorY, 64, 64, love.graphics.newImage('assets/meteor.png'))
end
```

After that i would like also to delete the object when it is outside of the screen. I know how to do that without oop but with oop i'm stuck...

Thanks you in advance !

How should i create the random spawn system ? Should i create many objects meteor from the meteor class blueprint inside the gameState.lua file ?

Comment: Call `love.math.setRandomSeed(os.time())` once in the very beginning of your game.  (Does LOVE2D have `os.time`?)

Comment: I gues it does. If not you could use something else, like battery seconds left or some recent touch coordinates for example to at least get a bit of variance

Comment: Love's math lib initializes random seed by itself, it is not needed.

Comment: Is `WINDOW_WIDHT` just a typo? (That's why you're supposed to paste ALL of your relevant sources into your question!).

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/Ws2aRp2n) works as expected. Problem might appear if second argument of your `love.math.random` call somehow ends up as `nil`. With your current code it should throw an error (*attempt to perform arithmetic on ... nil*).

Comment: @Green and isn't that because of that typo?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz OP didn't mention any error message but said that object's `x` is always the same. If `WINDOW_WIDHT` is not declared everything will quit with stack trace. What he is describing is similar to `random(0, nil) - meteorWidth` or when `WINDOW_WIDHT` is equal to `meteorWidth` (`random(0, 0)`). At this point the best way is to start debugger and find out.

Comment: Thanks, i have added the line math.randomseed(os.time()) before self.x = math.random(0, WINDOW_WIDHT - meteorWidth), now it works but how can i create a spawn system ? I have to create a meteor object from the meteor "blueprint file" every two seconds in a for loop inside the gameState file ?

Comment: @CPUCraft Wait, you were using `math.random`? Source you sent clearly says `love.math.random`. These are two different functions.

Comment: no, i have changed the line, now it's math.random and it works now. But now i don't know how to spawn multiple meteorit (enemies), should i create multiple meteorite object from the meteorit file ?

Comment: I think that i should create a meteorList array in the gameState class and every two seconds, create and add an instance/object meteor inside the array then draw every object that exist in the array... Is this the good way to create the spawn system ? If yes, how to delete every object that are outside of the screen/window ? By removing the object from the array ? Thanks and sorry for all these questions !

Comment: Thanks you all ! Now the spawn system work perfectly !